# rustup rust installation giving command not found error

Tags: rust

I installing rustc in Linux for school by using the rustup command as explained in the wiki at https://www.rust-lang.org/

> curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh`

The installation got completed but when i opened new terminal tab and when i run `rustc`in the new tab. i get the error `command not found`. I tried the find solutions and not find anything useful. Please help me.

Comment: After you issued the command in the shell, did you read over any output in the shell following its execution? Did it indicate whether the operation was successful or not?

Comment: I did not get any errors. It said open in new tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me the environment is not loaded. Check if have `. "$HOME/.cargo/env"` in your `$HOME/.bashrc` or `$HOME/.zshrc` file of the shell that you use. If its not already there add it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add cargo to your environment variables. If you're on a Mac, first open up the .zshrc using the following command:

`vim ~/.zshrc`

Then, copy the following line in this file:

`export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"`

Save and close this file. Exit this terminal and open up a new terminal. It should be added to your path now!